# My Spry Menu has been set up in INCLUDES but will not open in Browser

Tags: php, server-side-includes, spry

this is my first but not my last question

I have my index.html but the drop down menus coded in SPRY will not open when on the server . The include folder is there in there are 2 files 
jps_bute_Spry1.shtml  and
jps_bute_Spry2.shtml

Here the code in the header

```
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="jps_bute_live.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'turnDown' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp,shuffle,  etc...
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here the part in the body

```
 </div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="menu_container_panel_right" -->
  <div id="jps_bute_live_menu_container_right_panel">
    <!--#include file="includes/jps_bute_Spry1.shtml" -->
  </div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
  <div id="jps_bute_live_main_top_body"></div>
  <div id="jps_bute_live_main_body_container"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="main_body_container_panel_left" -->
    <div id="jps_bute_live_main_body_container_left_panel">
      <!--#include file="includes/jps_bute_Spry2.shtml" -->
    </div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="main_body_panel_right" -->
```

I believe there is something missing that I am not seeing on the server
Can anyone help in this matter?

Thx Ian

Comment: Spry code can be blocked by the browser if opened locally in some cases, are you opening it from a remote server or a local server by phisical path?

Comment: locally it is working. When I upload it on to the server anything that is in the includes folder cannot be seen  I believe it has got something to do with the htaccess file. I assume I don't have the right lines included.

Comment: I used Google to find an answer, The problem was with the htaccess. I added 3 lines of code and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
It was in htaccess. Some lines where missing to activate .shtml files in the include folder. I have added them and now it is working again.